# What is a timestamp?

Tags: ros, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is a timestamp? How is it related to the 3D location of an object? Why is it useful?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256916/what-is-a-timestamp?/) by [Rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/29580/rai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2017-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-14**:
@Rai: ROS Answers is definitely a website where we try to help out beginners, but we do expect a certain amount of effort on your side as well. We're happy to help, but could I ask you to include whatever you've already found yourself in future questions? That way we avoid duplicating answers.

**Comment by [Rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/29580/rai/) on 2017-03-14**:
Thank you for your comment. If you browse my questions, you will see I have asked and re-asked these questions and have tried to add further improvements, but yet nothing.

**Comment by [Rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/29580/rai/) on 2017-03-14**:
I was wondering if you could check [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/256226/find-3d-location-of-the-sensor-when-a-depth-image-arrives/) and tell me if I need to ask it in a different way, thank you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-14**:
Just an observation, but I get the impression that you are trying to learn all sorts of things at the same time. ROS is not easy and trying to learn about robotics / computer vision in general while also climbing the steep learning curve of ROS will most likely not be most efficient.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-14**:
Pick your battles and try to get a general understanding of things first, *then* try to translate those into ROS domain concepts, which will probably lead you to packages, nodes and techniques that you can use for that. Also, pick up a [book](http://wiki.ros.org/Books) or two.

**Comment by [Rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/29580/rai/) on 2017-03-14**:
Which means one or two months of sleeping on books. Do I have a shorter way to "just complete the mentioned project" or something like that, in two or three days? Okay, the answer is no, but still..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-14**:
Well I don't know what you want me to say. Unfortunately there is no magic way to do everything someone would want in no time whatsoever.

If your requirements are very close to something that an existing pkg provides, you could cut some corners, but you wouldn't gain any understanding.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-14**:
If you meant: are there any books which take you through a nr of example projects, then my answer is: yes, those exist. Just check out some of the books on the page I linked (anything *by example* would seem to apply here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Timestamp of e.g. an image ist the point of time, when the Image was captured. If robot moves through its operateing Environment the mounted sensors will move as well. Therefore, the timestamp together with the motion trayectory of your robot will help you to keep trace where each Image was captured.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/29580/rai/) on 2017-03-14**:
Oh, thank you now makes sense.. Thank you!!